# How to save and access server response around the app with C# (Xamarin Forms)?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create an app which receives json data from server and I want to know how can I access the saved server response around the app? For example, the json response can contain a key "score", "username", etc and need to display that on different screen, but after I push a new window (Navigation.PushModalAsync(...)), I can not access the received data from the new window.

So far, I was able to:

- Send post request to server
- Receive and deserialize the json

Now I need to be able to access the response all over the app, on different screens, but I am not able to do that.

```
ServerResponseObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerResponseObject>(json.ToString());
```

ServerResponseObject is a class created by me

**I want to be able to access the "result" variable inside different pages, screens. To access it globally.**

I have tried to declare a global variable and create a class, but the class is static and the server response is not static.

Any suggestions (or new approaches) on this problem, would be appreciated. Thanks

---

## Update

If I set my class "ServerResponseObject" as static, then I can no longer use this:

```
ServerResponseObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerResponseObject>(json.ToString());
```

That means, I would have to manually assign data from server response to every single class property and it's also difficult to update the Labels around the app, when the properties were changed

Comment: Why dont you put them in the local storage ? like to use sqlite or realm ?

Comment: I was hoping for a simpler solution, but I think that is the best solution, to use something like sqlite or realm. Thank you

Comment: Why won't using a static class work?

Comment: I've tried creating a class and assigning the server response to it, but I cannot access the new assigned (class) data on different navigation page. And cannot create a static class, because the data is dinamically updated from server response.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong.  A static class can contain dynamic data, and should be available throughout your app.

Comment: Yes, probably I'm doing it wrong. I did create a class and set some properties there, but to access it I need to create a new instance, right? Like "new ClassName" which will create a class with the default variables values, but I am not able to access it on a different page. Probably I'm missing something pretty simple. I thought I can just create a new class instance and use that instance around the app, but it seems that is not possible... or at least, I don't know how

Comment: If you want the response data to persist between app launches, you can also use your application's `Properties` dictionary to save and retrieve simple key value pairs. You can use something like `Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties` to access it from anywhere in your app.

Comment: @Stefan In your static class, create public static properties as well. `public static class MyStuffHolder { public static object MyStuff {get; set;} }` and you can access `MyStuff` without an instance of `MyStuffHolder`.

Comment: Lol, silly me. That's exactly what I wanted to use, static classes, but I forgot to add the "static" before class name and I assumed that it doesn't work. Thank you for your responses and suggestions

Comment: The use of static is evil ! in one move it makes your code untestable .

Comment: @BraveHeart Then what do you recommend? Going with the Database option?

Comment: If you want to keeo that data alive even after you turnoff the app , then use Database try out realm if you have not done it before it is super nice thing. Otherwise if you just want to keep the data accessable, then my approach would be is that you keep the results in an instance of the service that does the request and deserialization and put that instance inside a container (e.g. unity) as singleton then you resolve it anytime you need it. But if it is for me i would still go for the realm solution.

Comment: And to be honest i feel that your architecture can have a space for improvements , for example why dont you pass the data from one view to another ? 
Checkout Prism for Xamarin.Forms . you might find it interesting .

Comment: @BraveHeart Thanks. I plan to use realm for my next app, it will have an offline version too, but actual project is online only. I opted for the option to  have a class with these properties (username, score, etc) and use ViewModal and binding and a ViewModalLocator static class which will instantiate and keep track of ViewModal classes. However, I am still oscillating between this and realm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist your data over App restarts, you can either save it in the App.Current.Properties dictionary or use [James Montemagnos Settings Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin) which is probably better, due to it saving it via the platform specific data storage.

And you should not make the object that you want to save a static class in your project. Rather create a static property of ServerResponseObject and assign it the value from the json.